# How solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException Error extracting SQL target list from view SQL code

Tags: java, mysql

Someone knows how solve this error?

Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "SELECT" <K_SELECT>
at line 1, column 1.

Was expecting one of:

```
"ALTER"
"CALL"
"COMMENT"
"COMMIT"
"DECLARE"
"DELETE"
"DESCRIBE"
"DROP"
"EXEC"
"EXECUTE"
"EXPLAIN"
"INSERT"
"MERGE"
"REPLACE"
"SET"
"SHOW"
"TRUNCATE"
"UPDATE"
"UPSERT"
"USE"
"VALUES"
"WITH"

at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.generateParseException(CCJSqlParser.java:22439)
at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.jj_consume_token(CCJSqlParser.java:22286)
at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.SingleStatement(CCJSqlParser.java:229)
at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Statement(CCJSqlParser.java:75)
at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:49)
... 15 more
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Im working on a project in which the libraries in a jar formar are using jsqlparser and those libraries cant be touch by me

im using as database an mySQL database.

Comment: You might want to add the problematic query to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is the query generating the error: SELECT Group.obj AS X1 FROM Group

Answer (score 1):

This is a parsing exception from **JSqlParser**. This library is not able to successfully parse a given SQL statement.

I am not quite sure from your question, how limited your access to the used libraries is. **JSqlParser** for instance is actively developed (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser). So maybe you are simply using a version that is too old.

First, start to find the problematic SQL.

Now you have two choices:

1. Simply transform this SQL into a version **JSqlParser** understands.
2. Since you wrote you can't touch the libraries of your project, this one could be a no go: file an issue at github to make **JSqlParser** support your specific requirement and after this is solved, use the new version of JSqlParser.